# Different component element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

This is my component and here i have button and include another componet which also contains button. How to set two buttons next to each other. Button from this component and  I try using position absolute and right, top but is bad approach when window is resize.

```
<div md-dialog-content>
  <div class="section-top">
    <p id="title" style="float:left;">Adding document</p>
    <div md-dialog-actions style="float:right;">
      <button class="edm-button" md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-document-data></app-document-data>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only see 1 button in your code....

Comment: @Robert Wade second button is located in <app-doucment-data> this is component selector

Comment: @WalterWhite then post the HTML generated after page is rendered on the browser.

Comment: @WalterWhite tbh don't use the button in a child or parent component. Better use `@Output` or `@Input` (depend what component the parent is) when button is clicked.

Comment: @Swoox using '@input' and '@Output' is a good advice and i also will put button in this view

Comment: @WalterWhite Also if you want to make it for mobiles use `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {` in CSS. THen can edit the place so the button show on the right place again or make button smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty hard to read but I think I get your point.

You can use [flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for that :

```
<div md-dialog-content>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: center;">
    <p id="title">Adding document</p>
      <div md-dialog-actions>
        <button class="edm-button" md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <app-document-data></app-document-data>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just your opinion isn't this just bad pratice if using Angular?

Comment: Well, not at all, they even made a special library for that that [you can find here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Comment: Well I've read it, but it seems I don't quite understand it. Could you rephrase it please ?

Comment: If he just put the button in the same component it can't move to different places?

Comment: No, in the case of Angular, creating a component just means you can reuse it somewhere else. Using the tag (here `app-document-data`) just means "replace this tag with the content of the component". It won't affect the display !

Comment: It will if it change size again.

Comment: No it won't. The default flex value for growing & shrinking is 1, coupled with the `nowrap` attribute, it means noth buttons will remain the same size. But again, I'm giving him a trail to follow, not the perfect answer. I can't, with only that bunch of code.

Comment: Ty for explaining I can actually add this to my code :)

Comment: Well no problem ! As you can see in the answer, there's a link to a cheat sheet with all the CSS properties, but if you use Angular, I suggest you use the flex-layout module, that I sourced in my previous comment. Good luck !